# Conditional associations or scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have two models

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end
```

Now, I want to have convenient method to access approved accounts(:approved => true).
What is better to use, and why?

1. `has_many: approved_accounts, -> { where :approved => true }` for `Client` model

   or
2. `scope: approved, -> { where :approved => true }` for `Account` model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, *It Depends*. For Long answer, kindly read on...

- **Conditional associations** allows us to Customize the query that `ActiveRecord` will use to fetch the association. Use when you are sure that this condition is permanent & you will never-ever need access to data that doesn't fit the conditional(atleast not in this model) as Conditional associations are APPLIED to every query to `ActiveRecord` does to the association from that particular model.
- **Scope** It is basically, a class method for retrieving and querying objects. so what you are actually doing is defining the following method in your model.

  `class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.approved
      where(:approved => true)
    end
  end`

so `scope` is generally use to define short names for one or more regularly used query customization. But important difference is that `scope` is not auto-applied unless you use [`default_scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-default_scope) but conditional associations are auto-applied.

In your case, you want to show unapproved accounts in this model? If not, then use conditional association. Else use `scope`

Answer (score 1):

According to me, the `scope` solution seems the better:

As you probably know, to get the approved accounts of a client, you can do: `approved_accounts = client.accounts.approved` which is not less legible than: `approved_accounts = client.approved_accounts`

So not many difference here. But if in the future you want the list of all approved accounts (for statistics or whatever), with the scope solution, a single `approved_accounts = Account.approved` will be enough. But if you choose the client side, it will be trickier to get (understand: you will have to use the Client model).

Just consider than being approved is a property of an Account more than a property of a Client and it should be clearer that the scope is the best solution.

Hope this clarifies things.